# How to make simple <md-chip> work without <md-chips> in AngularJS Material?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

Please forgive me that my mother tongue is not English :)

I'm using AngularJS Material v1.1.1.
I'm finding a way to use simple `<md-chip>` without `<md-chips>`.

Here is an easy way in Vue Material: https://codesandbox.io/s/lyoqv4l0z?module=App.vue

```
<md-chip class="md-primary" md-deletable>Deletable</md-chip>
```

But I can not find the similiar way in AngularJS Material document.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdChip

**Here is my code:**
https://codepen.io/iMaeGoo/pen/EJaaqp

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <p>
        <md-chips ng-model="chips">
            <md-chip-template>
                {{ $chip }}
            </md-chip-template>
        </md-chips>
    </p>

    <p>
        <!-- I want to make this simple md-chip work here -->
        <md-chip>{{oneChip}}</md-chip>
    </p>
</body>
```

```js
angular.module('myApp',['ngMaterial']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.chips = ["A chip in chips!"];
    $scope.oneChip = "A chip without chips!";
});
```

How can I make `<md-chip>` work without `<md-chips>`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to rewrite CSS.

```css
md-chips {
  md-chips-wrap {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    cursor: inherit;
    width: fit-content;

    ._md-chip-input-container {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  md-chip {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

See: https://codepen.io/iMaeGoo/pen/BEyKem

The chip is still in chips component. It is not a good idea.